# Position relative not always on top

Tags: html, css, overflow, z-index

On my website: http://jonasolaussen.se/dev3/?page_id=6

I have Tooltips that shows when clicking on dates. The Tooltip are styled with position relative and z-index: 100; so they always are on top.

But the problems is when you click on dates to the far left/right half of the tooltip goes "under" the calendar and hides.

I have tried to put overflow: visible; on all elements on the entire page just to see if that is the problem, but it is not. I have also tried z-index: 10000000000000000; and so on. But nothing works. I do not understand why they are not on top of everything.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't the z-index but the attribut overflow hidden to fc-view fc-view-month fc-grid

Comment: Incredible! 

Thank you! I tried to put *{overflow: visible;} but id did not work. But when i pin point the elements it works.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On your actual page, your tooltips are on a container `<div class="fc-view fc-view-month fc-grid"` wich has property `overflow : hidden`

Just remove `overflow hidden` and tooltips will appear

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correct you have to delete oveflow: hidden .fc-view {} on your CSS
http://jonasolaussen.se/dev3/wp-content/plugins/booking-bank/css/plugins.css